# App crashes when coming back from an external url

Tags: angular, cordova

I have built a mobile app using angular 8.3.23 and cordova 9.00. When I open an external url and press the back button the app crashes with the message:
Application Error
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///android_asset/www/...)

Comment: what's the file its looking for? what's its role in your app\/

Comment: It's the part of the url that requests when pressing back button from an external url.

Application Error net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///android_asset/www/store/kandia-s-castle-resort-thalasso)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by installing **cordova-plugin-ionic-webview** and then changing base href from **"./"** to **"/"**.